# convert html to pdf with PyQT5 in python

Tags: python, pyqt5, html-to-pdf

I am encountering a problem with this code in order to convert an HTML input file to a PDF file.
The problem emerges when I want to specify page_width and page_height (in particular adding the lines between "app" and "page") and returns the following error:

AttributeError: module 'PyQt5.QtPrintSupport' has no attribute 'QPageSize'

Anybody knows how to solve it?

```
import os
import sys
import PyQt5

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets, QtPrintSupport
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import QPrinter
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPageSize


def html_to_pdf(html, pdf):
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

   custom_page_width = 8.5
   custom_page_height = 11
   custom_page_size_mm = QtCore.QSizeF(custom_page_width * 25.4, custom_page_height * 25.4)
   custom_page = QtPrintSupport.QPageSize(QtPrintSupport.QPageSize.Letter)
   custom_page.setRect(QtCore.QRectF(QtCore.QPointF(0, 0), custom_page_size_mm))

   printer = QtPrintSupport.QPrinter()
   printer.setPageSize(custom_page)

   page = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage()

def handle_print_finished(filename, status):
    print("finished", filename, status)
    QtWidgets.QApplication.quit()

def handle_load_finished(status):
    if status:
        page.printToPdf(pdf)
    else:
        print("Failed")
        QtWidgets.QApplication.quit()

page.pdfPrintingFinished.connect(handle_print_finished)
page.loadFinished.connect(handle_load_finished)
page.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(html))
app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":

   filename = r"<<input_path.html>>"
   print(filename)

   html_to_pdf(filename, r"<<output_path.pdf>>")
```

Answer (score 0):

`QPageSize` is in `QtGui`, not `QPrintSupport`. You've already imported it correctly:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPageSize
```

You can now refer to it as `QPageSize`. You get the error described by trying to access it as `QPrintSupport.QPageSize`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: thank you, but unfortunately seems to be a last problem.

---
The new code presents this error:
'QPageSize' object has no attribute 'setRect'
---

Is there a way to set CUSTOM width and length in PDF to obtain for example a single page instead of 6/7? (it's my purpose)

Comment: @fpisto As the [QPageSize](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpagesize.html) documentation clearly shows, there's no such function as `setRect()`. If you want a page with custom sizes, then you need to use the [proper constructor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpagesize.html#QPageSize-3) of QPageSize: `custom_page = QPageSize(custom_page_size_mm, QPageSize.Millimeter)`.